# Using Country Flags Emoji with flat design

Tags: android

I am getting the country flags images from emojis based on a country code list (e.g US, DE, BR, AR...)

But the flags have this "waving flag" shape.
It is possible to have it on a flat design shape?
You can see as a **"possible render"** on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regional_indicator_symbol

[image: Current look and fell]